# elsarticle/article two sided placement of float

Tags: floats

I have a image which I would like placed on page in full width, in a LaTeX document using `elsearticle` document class. My problem is that no matter what I throw at the figure it moves below three paragraphs.

I have used `[h]`, `[ht]`, `[!htb]` and more, this is the figure:

```
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{pictures/Results/growthhemoglobin}
    \caption{\textbf{A:} Growth chart of offsprings from day 1-29. There was no significant differences between the four groups before day 20. \textbf{B:} Overview of hemoglobin  concentration (g/dL) measured in the four different groups of offsprings at different time points (days). All groups were significant difference compared to control groups (CN) CN. A significant difference at day 14-18 between G19 and ID** were observed. At day $>28$ there was revealed a significant difference between G19 and ID*. Groups: Control (CN), iron deficiency (ID), postnatal five (P5). Data is presented as mean ± Standard Error of Mean.
        * \textit{p}$<$0.05, * \textit{p}$<$0.01, ** \textit{p}$<$0.001, ** \textit{p}$<$0.0001.}
    \label{fig:growthhemoglobin}
\end{figure*}
```

There are three `subsection`s before a `\FloatBarrier` and there is a `\FloatBarrier` in the beginning of the section. I have no problems in previous sections with this. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: As always on this site you are much more likely to get fast reactions if you post a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet like thus. Then others can easily copy and test your code. Also since you're using an image others do not have either replace it with a rule or use on of the images supplied by the mwe package (you don't need to use the package they are just convenient example images). Thirdly if `elsarticle.cls`  is not on ctan please provide a link to were others can download it.

Comment: @daleif it is in ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle :)

Comment: I'm saying if it's not, there are so many journal classes that are not regularly added to ctan and a lot of people just assumes that others know about them. Or where to get them.

Comment: Changed it missed read your comment, sorry for being a d*** but I am getting pissed :( It is working in the section right before :(

Comment: Btw as far as I know there is no support for placement adjustments for figure* (might be wrong though). Why a re you typing those p's in text mode? And no the full p<0.05 in math mode?

Comment: The please provide a full minimal example others can test. My guess is that you just got luckily and thought it did something but actually it did not.

Comment: As far as I can gather elsarticle is just a modified version of the article class, does not seem to change figure* placement, meaning that the figure* is always placed at the top of the next page with next to no control by the user.

Comment: `figure*` only has `t` and `p` options not `h` or `b` (@daleif)

Comment: it isn't really possible to debug your fragment but note that `figure*` always comes, at the earliest, on the page after its position in the source, so you may need to move it earlier in the source file to allow it to come on the desired page in the output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I knew there was some information somewhere, but hard on a tablet. Does this imply that a figure* will never appear on the page that it was added or is that a consequence of twocolumn?

Comment: @daleif `figure*` never appears on the page it was added in two column documents (in one column `figure8` doesn't really exist and it is just treated as `figure`

Comment: all of `[h], [ht], [!htb]`  make it more likely the figure goes to the end of the document. `[h]` doesn't allow it anywhere, `[ht]` is same as [t]` so prevents the figure being on a float page, `[!htb]` is same as `[!t]` and so also prevents the figure being on a float page.